# Error processing Instruction 0: sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match

Tags: solana-program, transactions, cli

I got this error.

*Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved✔️

In my case I had a function that had two shipments of balances. One through the system program with transfer and another through try_borrow_mut_lamports()?.

First you have to put the **transfer** function and then the **try_borrow_mut_lamports()** function