# Anchor error: Error processing Instruction 0: sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match

Tags: anchor, solana-program

I am running into the error, in my Anchor program:

`[Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match]`

I am doing a spl-token transfer through CPI:

```
    anchor_spl::token::transfer(
        CpiContext::new(
            token_program.to_account_info(), 
        Transfer {
            from: sender_token_account.to_account_info(),
            to: receiver_token_account.to_account_info(),
            authority: user.to_account_info(),
        }),
        amount.into()
    )?;
```

In the same transaction I am also reallocating the size of a PDA.

Anyone has a hint on how to avoid this error?

Comment: I dont think PDA reallocation has anything to do with this error. Can you explain more on the changes happening in this code

Comment: I am doing two things:
1. Transfer SPL Tokens
2. Reallocate PDA account

I tried to do them separately, then both work fine. But combining them in one function is throwing this error

Comment: Please post the full instruction logic. There's not enough information in the provided sample to debug why the account balances would be off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the same problem here:

[*https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/error-processing-instruction-0-sum-of-account-balances-before-and-after-instruc*](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/4481/error-processing-instruction-0-sum-of-account-balances-before-and-after-instruc)

Be very careful when making transactions. Put the native ones first and then the one you use with pda

If my contribution does not help you, I invite you to share the code to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you solve this? I am having the exact same issue.

I am able to realloc (increase and decrease) if I remove the token transfer code in the instruction. I'm also able to do the token transfer by itself if I remove the realloc.

But if I combine them both I can only increase the PDA's size, not decrease, and I get the same error `[Error: failed to send transaction: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: sum of account balances before and after instruction do not match]`.

```
use anchor_spl::{
  associated_token::AssociatedToken,
  token::{self, Mint, Token, TokenAccount, Transfer as SplTransfer},
};

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(description: String)]
pub struct EditProfile<'info> {
  #[account(mut)]
  pub owner: Signer<'info>,

  #[account(mut)]
  pub token_mint: Account<'info, Mint>,

  #[account(mut,
    associated_token::mint = token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = owner,
  )]
  pub owner_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

  #[account(mut, seeds = [b"user", owner.key().as_ref()], bump)]
  pub user: Account<'info, User>,

  // 
  #[account(
    init_if_needed,
    payer = owner,
    associated_token::mint = token_mint,
    associated_token::authority = user,
  )]
  pub user_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,

  #[account(
    mut,
    seeds = [b"profile", owner.key().as_ref()],
    bump,
    realloc = 8 + Post::BASE_SIZE + description.len(),
    realloc::payer = owner,
    realloc::zero = false,
  )]
  pub profile: Account<'info, Post>,

  pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
  pub token_program: Program<'info, Token>,
  pub associated_token_program: Program<'info, AssociatedToken>,
  pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
}

pub fn edit_profile(
  ctx: Context<EditProfile>,
  description: String,
) -> Result<()> {
  let profile = &mut ctx.accounts.profile;

  profile.edit(description);

  // instruction works if this is removed:
  token::transfer(
    CpiContext::new(
      ctx.accounts.token_program.to_account_info(),
      SplTransfer {
        from: ctx.accounts.owner_ata.to_account_info(),
        to: ctx.accounts.user_ata.to_account_info(),
        authority: ctx.accounts.owner.to_account_info(),
      }
    ),
    COST_TO_EDIT_PROFILE,
  )?;

  Ok(())
}
```